# proof: If $k ∈ \mathbb Z,$ then $\gcd(4k − 1, 4k + 1) = 1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

**Claim:** If $k \in \mathbb Z$, then $\gcd(4k − 1, 4k + 1) = 1$.

**Proof:** First of all, $1$ divides every integer so that $1$ divides both $4k + 1$ and $4k − 1$.

That is,
$1$ is a common divisor of $4k + 1$ and $4k − 1$.

Now suppose that $m$ is a common divisor of $4k + 1$ and $4k − 1$. If $m ≤ 0$, then certainly $m < 1$.

Suppose that $m > 0$. Since $m$ divides both $4k - 1$ and $4k + 1$, $m$ divides every linear combination
of $4k + 1$ and $4k − 1$.

In particular, $m$ divides $(4k + 1) − (4k − 1) = 2$.

Since $m \mid 2$ and $2$ is prime,
$m = 1$ or $m = 2$.

But $4k + 1 = 2(2k) + 1$ is odd and thus is not divisible by $2$. Thus $m = 1$, and so
$m \leq 1$.

So $1$ is the greatest common divisor of $4k + 1$ and $4k − 1$.

i'm supposed to find a flaw in the proof or explain why it's correct and i'm having trouble finding any flaw. All the steps look logical but i want to make sure that there isn't a step missing out that i just am not noticing.

Comment: Seems right to me.

Comment: I've added LaTeX code for the math in your question while also providing an example or two of how to format text on Math.SE. Take a look at the code to get a feel for how to write up questions in a readable way on this website. For a more thorough reference regarding math syntax on this site, see [this quick guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hardly the most efficient proof, but it seems okay to me.

Comment: That's totally true, because of there is only two cases, and you checked them.